# curl - Doesn't work within a proxy - 307 - Authorization Required

Tags: proxy, curl

I'm trying to use curl inside a proxy.

I read over the curl docs and some answers here in askUbuntu but didn't solve my problem.

I'm trying to use this specific command with curl:

```
curl -x http://10.127.3.34:8080 -U user:123456 http://localhost:8085
```

But it's not working, check the screenshot below about what I am getting:
[image]

I set the `~/.curlrc` too, look below:
[image]

I don't know what else I should do. Please, can someone say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: dont post screenshot. copy paste the text please :)

Comment: oh and you need to supply the "Authorization" tag See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044315/how-to-set-the-authorization-header-using-curl

Comment: Sorry. I'm using a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu Server with VMWare Workstation. I tried to copy the text and paste here but some reason it doesn't work :'(

Comment: well you are of the hook for this once ;-) see if the link helps and then feel free to self-answer this question